# Windows Error Registering Binaries

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-registry, windows-update, .net-framework

After installing some windows updates, a ANSYS SIWAVE will not start and immediately crashes. Reinstalling didn't fix it, two of the updates were permanent so cannot be rolled back, the third update when rolled back made the program successfully install and partially start up and then close instead of immediately closing.

I uninstalled the program and deleted the third update's software download and had Windows update reinstall the update cleanly. I tried to install Ansys Electronics Suite again but it would still fail to install.

The error happens at a point called "machine specific configuration", it fails registering two binary excutables "reg_ansysedt.exe" & "reg_siwave.exe" with an error code: 3221227010 for both executables.

[image]

Windows Updates in question (IDK why I have more than 3 different numbers but they changed through uninstalling and reinstalling somehow):
KB4576478
KB4571756
KB4566782
KB4577266
KB4565503

Comment: No information about what exactly happened, so no possibility of an answer. If System Restore is enabled, roll back to before these updates were done, then disable them.

Comment: @harrymc I restored the system to a restore point to remove the "permanent" updates but the same problem occured. After installing the updates again, all system restore points were gone.

Comment: Post is closed.

Comment: @harrymc I added a screenshot of the error and these are the only details I have so please reopen the question so I can get some hints at least.

Comment: @Ramhound I had 3 updates installed on 9/9, apparently these were the ones predownloaded and ready to install in inactive hours, when I uninstalled, restored a system restore point, deleted the softwaredistribution & catroot2 folders, it downloaded and installed the newer versions. Also some KBs don't appear in the updates history in the settings but appear in the control panel "view installed updates".

Comment: Currently installed:
KB4571756
KB4576478
KB4577266

Comment: [Seems like a software bug Ansys should solve](https://forum.ansys.com/discussion/20206/ansys-maxwell-error-3221227010).  **KB4571756 can be uninstalled** I would try that for a week.  I strongly suspect this is a bug with the program itself.  Without a debug error it will be extremely difficult to do additional diagnostics

Comment: @ramhound apparently I can only roll back so much but there was one update that remained, I think it was the security update.

Comment: Only KB4577266 cannot be uninstalled due to it being a service stack update

Comment: Post was closed by a moderator, not me.

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled the update and the error is gone, the KB4565503 is now in position, I guess I miss-read that it's a different code at first and thought KB4571756 didn't install since there were still 3 updates on 9/9. Now Ansys partly opens and crashes I'm not sure how can I solve that.

Comment: EDIT TO PREVIOUS COMMENT, "thought KB4571756 didn't install since" to "thought KB4571756 didn't uninstall since"

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Updates in question (IDK why I have more than 3 different numbers but they changed through uninstalling and reinstalling somehow): KB4576478 KB4571756 KB4566782 KB4577266 KB4565503

If the problem surfaced after installing KB4571756, you should uninstall temporarily, as that would be a problem the developer of the software must address. However, if that isn't an acceptable solution, you can also configure the proper environmental variable to resolve this problem.

Within an elevated command prompt issue the following commands.  You might have to create the system variable if it doesn't already exist.

```
setx /m ANSYS_EM_DONOT_PRELOAD_3DDRIVER_DLL 1
```

The following appears to the official guidance provided by Ansys at this time.

> A recent Windows update, Microsoft update KB4571756, results in one of
> the Windows functions (DescribePixelFormat) crashing on startup.
>
> For versions 2018.0 and newer, please try setting the environment
> variable ANSYS_EM_DONOT_PRELOAD_3DDRIVER_DLL=1 to get around the
> problem.

Sources:

- [Ansys Maxwell error 3221227010](https://forum.ansys.com/discussion/20206/ansys-maxwell-error-3221227010)
- [ERROR : [reg ansysedt exe] AnsysEM19.2](https://forum.ansys.com/discussion/20291/error-reg-ansysedt-exe-ansysem19-2)
- [Ansys Maxwell error 3221227010](https://forum.ansys.com/discussion/comment/92181#Comment_92181)

Comment: This answer only applies to supported versions of Ansys Maxwell.  This answer is not applicable to earlier versions prior to ADET 2018.0 and newer, the only solution with those versions, is to install the update that breaks the application. **It does not appear Ansys has any plans to fix the issue on those earlier versions.** That will effectively break those versions on newer versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the environment variable ANSYS_EM_DONOT_PRELOAD_3DDRIVER_DLL=1 to get around the problem, I've had the same issue w/ R20.2 and this fixed it.
As reported here: https://forum.ansys.com/discussion/20206/ansys-maxwell-error-3221227010

Comment: Please cite and quote the relevant information by editing your answer.